# Paypal Sandbox - IPN Not working

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

My site is not receiving IPN from paypal sandbox. I verified working of my notify.php page by sending manual IPN VIA "IPN Simulator" and it works fine. But receiving no IPN from regular purchase simulation.

I checked the IPN history from my sandbox-test account. IPN end up in Failed after multiple retries.

> Date/time created    |   Message ID       | **Status**     | Transaction ID
>
> 1/30/2012 23:06 PST  | 0J990932SN848805V  | **Retrying**   | 1C574181PD653873S
>
> 1/30/2012 22:47 PST  | 8UY41985U65227626  | **Failed**     | 7UM32625T8929325L
>
> 1/30/2012 22:32 PST  | 36444784FH458323T  | **Sent**       | 7L3718344F253661J
>
> 1/30/2012 22:28 PST  | 5KA14796R82961455  | **Failed**     | 9PU30039G7583750S

I can't figure out the issue! Is it a problem at my end or something wrong at Sandbox like overloaded or etc.?

Comment: Can you provide code from your `notify.php`?

Comment: @aviral Yes it worked. And the strangest part is that the same code automatically started working then next morning!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranty that IPN will work for Sandbox each time. Some responses can be returned after few hours or even never.

Also, be sure that:

- your return URL is public (not in local network like "localhost")
- does not have port number
- is not behind firewalls, routers etc (accessible from anywhere Internet)
- your script should not have any errors. use logging or send an email in the beginning of the script
- go to your PayPal seller account Profile ->Selling Preferences ->Instant Payment Notification Preferences, and confirm that URL is correct

For final test, use real PayPal accounts and send small amount of money to test.